# qml viewer loading new window

Tags: qml

I test the following code posted at [1](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/declarative-modelviews-webview-newwindows-qml.html)

The qml viewer cannot open the new window and its progress is always 0.1 , what is the problem?

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import QtWebKit 1.0

Grid {
    columns: 3
    id: pages
    height: 300; width: 600

    Component {
        id: webViewPage

            WebView {
                id: webView
                height: 300; width: 600
                newWindowComponent: webViewPage
                newWindowParent: pages
                url: "newwindows.html"

                onLoadStarted: console.log("Started"+url)
                onLoadFinished: console.log("Finished"+url)
                onLoadFailed: console.log("Failed")
                onProgressChanged: console.log(progress)
                onUrlChanged: console.log("Changed"+progress+url)
            }
    }

    Loader { sourceComponent: webViewPage }
}
```

Comment: You are most probably behind a proxy, which need to be set manually through the Qt code, for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Worth trying to actually create a new window using the `Window` element to see if you have any luck. I'd expect the window to launch whether or not the data is coming through. See here:

https://www.qt.io/blog/2011/08/26/toplevel-windows-and-menus-with-qt-quick

Comment: Here is the link with working images: https://web.archive.org/web/20121214040602/http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/08/26/toplevel-windows-and-menus-with-qt-quick/